# No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

This is a very annoying problem, I'm setting up cookies authentication on my asp.net core project and sometimes this error occurs and sometimes it doesn't!

There is no pattern! It just starts throwing the error and suddenly it stops, then start again...

The exception is:

> InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to
>   handle the scheme: MyAuthScheme

This is really really annoying!
Here is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public const string AuthenticationSchemeName = "MyAuthScheme";

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemeName,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

And this is my authentication code:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(Startup.AuthenticationSchemeName, new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookie")));
```

any help on this?

Comment: Could you simply change the constant AuthenticationSchemeName to a string literal? So: AuthenticationScheme = "CookieAuth" (and do the same in your authentication code). Tell me if it occurs again or not.

Comment: Is there a place you use `MyAuthScheme`?

Comment: Same thing Danny...

Comment: sorry adem, I copied the error message before updating the value of AuthenticationSchemeName... I edited the question to reflect my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing this same issue and by digging into the source code, I discovered that for some reason, sometimes the `IHttpAuthenticationFeature.Handler` doesn't get set, and that's the reason why this error occurs. This is indeed very annoying and I fixed this issue by doing the following:

Expose your `CookieAuthenticationOptions`. I did this inside my `Startup` class:

```
public static readonly CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    //... your settings here
};
```

Then in your `Configure()`, it becomes:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
```

Then right before calling `SignInAsync`, you do:

```
if (HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>()?.Handler == null)
{
    var handler = (AuthenticationHandler<CookieAuthenticationOptions>)Activator.CreateInstance(cookieAuthenticationHandlerType);
    await handler.InitializeAsync(Startup.cookieAuthenticationOptions, HttpContext, logger, UrlEncoder.Default);

    var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>() ?? new HttpAuthenticationFeature();
    feature.Handler = handler;

    HttpContext.Features.Set(feature);
}
```

You also need:

```
private static readonly Type cookieAuthenticationHandlerType = typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler");
```

And inject these 2 dependencies in your constructor like:

```
public LoginController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    this.HttpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(this.GetType());
}
```

Ps: I don't know if this is a bug or what... but I hope it gets fixed in the next release.

Comment: I just filed a bug on the aspnet/Identity github repo:https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/978 can you guys comment and add the relevant library versions, it might help them in correcting the issue.

Comment: I am getting the same issue, I have tried you code but unfortunstly it didn't work in my case as there is a handler on HttpContext - I am using `.UseIISIntegration()` - It just doesn't handle my custom schema name.
The docs make it seem so simple https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie ....

Comment: I just stumbled upon https://zogface.wordpress.com/2016/09/13/custom-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-core/
I will have a go at implementing it when I get some time, it is important to try and understand why this error occurs, I get the same error but the reasons seem to be different

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Bruno's solution did work, but the main issue for me was that had UseMVC before UseIdentity, so:

```
//Identity must be placed before UseMVC()
app.UseIdentity();
app.UseMvc();
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into a similar issue using IdentityServer4 I needed to explicity add a signin-schema named the same as the variable or constant it was requesting.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    //Replace the Authentication Scheme with MyAuthScheme
    AuthenticationScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
});
```