# System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorize-attribute, kestrel-http-server

Scenario:

1. Create a New Asp.Net Core (version 1.0.0) project
2. Choose the Web API template
3. Add the `[Authorize]` attribute on the default ValuesController
4. Run the application

If I run the application with IIS and make a GET request to `http://localhost:60513/api/values` I get the expected `401 Unauthorized error`

If however I run the application with Kestrel (e.g: `dotnet run`) and make a GET request to `http://localhost:5000/api/values` I get a `500 Internal Server Error` with the following exception at kestrel:

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/values
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: .
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HKUMMBBBQ6AU": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<ChallengeAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 282.8427ms 200
```

My question is **Why my application has different result depending on the server hosting it?** Why Kestrel and IIS handle the Authorization differently?

Please note that there are similar questions in StackOverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825058/no-authentication-handler-is-configured-to-handle-the-scheme-automatic) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968422/no-authentication-handler-is-configured-to-handle-the-scheme) but they all are for more complex scenarios where filters or middleware are involved.

I do not have any middleware in the AspNet pipeline other than MVC, and all the code but the `[Authorize]` attribute is automatically generated by the AspNet Web Api template.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on correct usage of tags

Comment: any suggestion on what tags shouldn't be there?

Comment: _You should not force a tag into your title._

Comment: I am desperate to know the answer to this as well - any updates? Should we ask the ASP.Net core team on a GitHub Issue?

Comment: @user917170 See this thread here https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/967. 
I opened time ago this issue with AspNet Security

Comment: And, why would want to use the [Authorize] attribute if you haven't set any Authentication mechanism?

Comment: because a plain Authorize will deny entry to anonymous requests, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/967) in AspNet Security, the Authorize attribute on any action or controller requires at least one auth middleware in the pipeline in order to issue challenges.
When using IIS the IIS middleware is used but when using Kestrel there is no auth middleware dealing with this therefore we need to add our own.